# Use GetAsync with username+password in header (REST API)

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, authentication, xamarin

I need to pass `UserName` and `Password` as header-key to get a token. I tested `GET` method in Postman and it worked fine. However I cannot do the same in my C# code as I have trouble to send `UserName` and `Password` as header-keys.

In my code I used `PostAsync` (see code) but it didn't worked since `(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)` were always `false` no matter what. So I guess I have to roll with `GetAsync` to make it work. But I don't know how I pass `UserName` and `Password` as header-value.

My `LoginVm` just contain `UserName` and `Password`

```
    public static async Task<Token> Authentication(LoginVm vm) {

        Token token = null;

        string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
        var client = new HttpClient();

        //How to use GetAsync instead?
        var result = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://x.com/.../login"),
                                      new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode) { 
            string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) {

                token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(json);
            }
        }
        return token;
    }
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: your method is async so instead of `var result = ().Result` you can do `var result = await ()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", yourCredentials)
    var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(yourBaseUrl);
}
```

since you mentioned that `GET` works fine.
Then Assuming that you have a class for Token like this:

```
public class Token
{
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

you can add this line for deserializing the reponse:

```
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);
```

and access the `token`.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do I keep "Basic" or should I replace it? Also. I can't use `.IsSuccessStatusCode` like `if(responseString.IsSuccessStatusCode)`